# Mint Gold Dust - [NFT] ERC 1155 Not Displaying In MetaMask Mobile App Wallet

Tags: metamask, erc-1155, opensea

In previous iterations of our build we were able to view erc-1155's minted via our [platform](https://www.mintgolddust.com/) from the MetaMask mobile application, however, now neither our NFT's or contract address are displaying in the MetaMask app -> wallet -> "NFTs" tab.

It is worthy to note that we do comply to the OpenSea standard and are identified on their platform [here](https://opensea.io/collection/mint-gold-dust). Also, this issue was noticed within 24h of OpenSea implementation and we are not using ownable in our current iteration.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but could it be that the OpenSea contract address is pointing to the Proxy address and not the ERC-1155 contract? I'm not sure how Metamask handles the displays of NFTs, OpenSea seems to be able to handle a proxy contract address, but maybe there's a limitation in MetaMask that only looks for ERC-1155 contract inheritance specifically to render in the wallet. Maybe follow up with the Metamask community forum at https://community.metamask.io/ to see if someone else has encountered the same issue with NFTs minted via use of an ERC1967Proxy upgradeable contract as you have implemented?

Comment: There's also an article [here](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360058238591-NFT-tokens-in-your-MetaMask-wallet#) that has the steps to manually add the NFT, does this also not work?